# How to see if the given date is between two other datetimes objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I want to see if the user booked date is in between two other datetimes objects inside database .

I have two different times in my table start_time and end_time, so the start_time means when the booking begins and the end_time means when it will end, here is the code:

```
def parse_time(time):
    tdateime = str(time)
    date = parse(tdateime)
    return date

start = '2017-08-23 11:00:00'
end = '2017-08-23 11:50:00'

p1 = parse_time(start)
p2 = parse_time(end)
p3 = 'the date to be checked'

check_is_free = Appointment.query.filter(Appointment.start_time == p1).filter(Appointment.end_time == p2).first()
original_start_date = check_is_free.start_time
original_end_date = check_is_free.end_time
if check_is_free:
    if original_start_date <= p3 <= check_is_free.end_time:
        error = 'already reserved.'
        return jsonify({'occupied':error})
```

The end here is the service time period , for instance, the appointment starts at 11:00 and the service is 50 minutes by time, `timedelta` will add this 50 minutes to start time , so the final result will be 11:50 and this period of time must be busy and you can't make a book between this period.

If the user want to book for a service for example today at '11:30:00' it should give him the error message which is **already reserved**, but how can i get the third date ??, in fact , i am using `bootstrap-datepicker` to choose the datetime where i have just one field to choose the start date and time.

I've tried to make a few changes by parsing the start time and to put it value in variable **p3**, but here it will ignore all the code above and the appointment will be accepted since **p3** is the same as **start**, if the start time matches in **check_is_free** it will give me the booked service and here the error will raise, but if i changed the start time by just one minute the **check_is_free** will return a None , thats mean the appointment will be accepted which i won't .

Comment: This has nothing to do with flask as far as I know

Comment: The snippet is token from my Flask App, so i tagged it as a Flask question !!

Comment: `date.since_epoch in start.since_epoch..end..since_epoch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just filter to find if any `Appointment`s overlap with the user's desired appointment window? I mean something like:

```
# User's desired appointment window is start_time to end_time 

# an appointment is not overlapping, if
# - the end_time is before an existing start time, or
# - the start_time is after an existing end time
overlapping = session.query(Appointment).filter(
    not_(
        or_(Appointment.start_time > end_time,
             Appointment.end_time < start_time)))
```

Here's a complete working example which you can try out:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, DateTime, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_, not_

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class Appointment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'appointments'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    end_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session()
existing_appointment = Appointment(id=1,
                                   start_time=datetime(2017,8,23,11,0),
                                   end_time=datetime(2017,8,23,11,50))
session.add(existing_appointment)
session.commit()

def check_appointment(start_time):
    end_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=20)
    overlapping = session.query(Appointment).filter(
        not_(
            or_(Appointment.start_time > end_time,
                Appointment.end_time < start_time)))
    return not overlapping.count()

print('check 2017-08-23 11:30 (should be False): {}'.format(check_appointment(datetime(2017,8,23,11,30))))
print('check 2017-08-23 10:30 (should be True): {}'.format(check_appointment(datetime(2017,8,23,10,30))))
```

Comment: # - or the start_time is before an existing start time and the end_time is after an existing end time.

Comment: you could simplify the expression by negating the non-overlapping condition: `overlapping = not(start > existing_end or end < existing_start)`

Comment: Thanks that's much much better! That's what I get for answering questions late at night. :)

Comment: Thanks for your interests guys :). Now, the overlapping is not looping it gives a count of 0 every time even that the start_time and end_time is between already existing start and end times !!

Comment: I've created two variables, `user_start = parse_time('2017-08-23 11:30:00')` and `user_end = user_start + timedelta(minutes=50)` , the pre-existed start and end are `start = parse_time('2017-08-23 11:00:00')` `end = parse_time('2017-08-23 11:50:00')`, as you can see **user_start** is in between **11:00** and **11:50** , with these variables overlapping return False !

Comment: @makmani I'm not sure what the problem is, but I've updated my answer to include a complete example, using your example start/end times. Obviously you'll have to point to your actual database and your schema likely has info other than start/end time, but a working example should help you figure out where the problem is. :)

Comment: @dshockley, salute :), now i understand , the whole problem was that i compared the date with start_time not with end_time, your example above exactly did what i need and it helped me a lot, a big thank ;) .